# dart: is there a way to avoid calling "super" every time I extend a class?

Tags: flutter, inheritance, dart, abstract-class, super

I guess the code below is more clear than any explaination

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/a5107762d7f5d564f0f20206ddbd48d1

as for the title: is there a way to avoid calling "super" every time I extend a class?

thank you

Comment: If the base class had a default constructor that could take no arguments, you wouldn't need to explicitly call `super()`.  Otherwise, no.  A derived class must invoke a base class constructor somehow; if you don't explicitly use `super` and if the base class constructor isn't the default constructor or if it requires arguments, how would the compiler know which one should be called?

Comment: I tough so, I just how somebody has an hacky workaround for this

Comment: With an architecture where you need to pass arguments to the base class constructor, it's impossible.  You possibly could redesign your classes so that the base class instead provides `a` and `b` getters and relies on the derived class to override them, and then the base class constructor could take no arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently the answer is no, yet I do not feel that there are the basis for a feature request to dartlang